# My labels aren't moving to the column and rows I want them to

Tags: python, tkinter

I want my labels and entry widgets and different rows but they automatically move to the top. What do I do to do that? Is there a simple function I could use?

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

root.resizable(width = False, height = False)

label_1 = Label(root, text="Text")
label_2 = Label(root, text="Text2")

entry1 = Entry(root)
entry2 = Entry(root)

label_1.grid(row=4, column=2, sticky=E)
label_2.grid(row=5, column=2, sticky=E)

entry1.grid(row=4, column=3, sticky=E)
entry2.grid(row=5, column=3, sticky=E)

checkbox = Checkbutton(root, text="Check me")
checkbox.grid(columnspan=2)
```

Also do you know how to add sub frames? I searched but the examples were all with classes and I was left confused. I of course also want it to be in a specific column and row without automatically getting moved somewhere else.

Comment: rows that don't contain anything have a height of zero. You could put them in row 4 or row 4000, if the other rows are empty they will still appear at the top.

Comment: Regarding your question about adding sub-frames: just call the `grid()` method of an instance of one with the desired `row=y`, `column=x` values.

Comment: I get that if it's empty it's moved to the top. I just want to know how to change that.

Comment: The workaround it would be to create the missing rows and put something in them, just make it a blank something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Empty rows and columns have size 0.  Blank labels can be used to create blank space.

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
dummy = Label(root, text='\n')
label_1 = Label(root, text="Text")
label_2 = Label(root, text="Text2")
entry1 = Entry(root)
entry2 = Entry(root)

dummy.grid()
label_1.grid(row=4, column=2, sticky=E)
label_2.grid(row=5, column=2, sticky=E)
entry1.grid(row=4, column=3, sticky=E)
entry2.grid(row=5, column=3, sticky=E)

checkbox = Checkbutton(root, text="Check me")
checkbox.grid(columnspan=2)
```